# http request error angular 4.3 HttpClientModule

Tags: javascript, angular, http

The image below shows the type of error thats happening.
I have the httpclient implemented in the module.ts file and that seems to be fine.
I have checked the package.json file to make sure angular is up to date.
when I take private out the initial error goes away but doesn't resolve the issue as when I put this.http.get() request it gives an underline red error for the http in the request and states:
[ts] Property 'http' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
The constructor error states:
[ts] A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.

[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXdJN.png)

Comment: Looks like you've misspelled `constructor`. By the way, it;s usually a good idea to paste your code into the question instead of a picture :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have misspelled `constructor` as `contstructor` in your code as per your image. modify it and it should work fine .

Comment: Haha Thank you for your speedy response, I just noticed there myself. Silly mistake.